# Display SQL database name in ToolstripLabel

Tags: vb.net

Please .. how to display the name of my database in ToolstripLabel1

With this code the name of the database will be displayed in TextBox1.. but when I tried to write ToolstripLabel1 instead of TextBox1 I get an error.

My code :

```
 Private Sub Get_DataBase_Name()
        Db_Connection()
        InfoGetDataName = New DataTable
        Using AdapterGetDataName As New SqlDataAdapter(" SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName ", Con)
            AdapterGetDataName.Fill(InfoGetDataName)
            TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", InfoGetDataName, "DataBaseName")
        End Using
    End Sub
```

In Form1 Load :  `Get_DataBase_Name()`

Thank you in advance for help .Cordially.AABIDINE

Comment: Please explain better what is the error message (if any)?

Comment: Hello Steve ..The error message is : Databindings is not a member of system windows Forms.ToolStripLabel

Comment: So. you can't use DataBindins with a ToolstripLabel

Comment: Thank you Steve ..i can not change this databindings in the code in a way that i can display the name in ToolstripLabel ??

Comment: But why do your need DataBindings in a ToolstripLabel? Just set its Text with the result of your query.

Comment: Why please .I am very beginner and I could not put the text of the Toolstriplabel in my query

Comment: Any idea please masters ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need this

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", InfoGetDataName, "DataBaseName")
```

just replace it with

```
ToolStripLabel1.Text = "DataBaseName"
```

in addition since i think you want to display the value of the result of your query to toolstriplabel1, your query will result to 1 row with one cell
try this code.

```
ToolStripLabel1.Text = (dtbale.Rows(0)).ItemArray(0).ToString
```

Comment: Thank you PANDA for help.But when i put this code and i run project i have in ToolStripLabel1 .. only this word ( DataBaseName ).Cordially

Comment: i would like to know more about the details of you're trying to do. may i know what is the purpose of using this line TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", InfoGetDataName, "DataBaseName") ??

Comment: Thank you PANDA.Very nice of you.Now it work perfectly.Thank you for all.Cordially.ABE